# Organizing Long Nested Paths Across Multiple Files with Interceptors in Ballerina

Tags: interceptor, ballerina

I am exploring Ballerina for building APIs and leveraging its declarative style for defining endpoints and services. However, I am faced with the challenge of managing long nested paths, exemplified by the structure below:

```
/api/v1/ - with interceptor
    - a          GET, POST
    - a/:aId     GET, PATCH, DELETE
    - a/:aId/b   GET, POST
    - a/:aId/b/:bId  GET, PATCH, DELETE ( need an interceptor at this level )
    - a/:aId/b/:bId... goes on to 4-6 levels of nested resources
    - several top level resources similar to /api/v1/a
```

Currently, I have organized these paths into multiple service files.

I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to add path parameters to the service path?
2. Can service files be nested in any way?
3. Can interceptors or decorators be applied to individual resource functions?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers for the above three questions:

1. Direct addition of path parameters to the service path is not supported in Ballerina, we have the flexibility to move the variable parts to the resource function URL.
2. Generally, we have the flexibility to structure your Ballerina project in a nested manner. refer to the documentation available at [Organizing Ballerina Code](https://ballerina.io/learn/organize-ballerina-code/)
3. we can engage interceptors based on the verb and the path at service level. Just like routers in express.js